# Cron 4 Minutes inaccurate Debian Buster

Tags: cron, debian-buster

I use Cron to update an hourly report. I give the following time value:

```
0 * * * *
```

But the report is always 4 Minutes too early

[image]

Checking the System time is correct and in sync with NTP.

Any ideas?

Comment: Great that you solved it, but please don't add `solved` to your question. Post an answer and accept it instead. This will mark the question as "solved" in the system. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. syslog is correct:

```
Jan 30 10:00:01 CRON[25825]: (root) CMD (vnstati -h -o /var/www/..../image.png > /dev/null 2>&1)
```

The Bug seems to be inside the PNG Generator of `vnstati`

```
stat image.png

Modify: 2020-01-30 10:00:01.380296387 +0100
```